Laragon's PHP version changed but Terminal shows old version
I have installed Laragon on my drive G:/Laragon . But my Visual Code is on C:/ . I dont know whether it is a root cause of the problem, but however if I change Laragon PHP version in Laragon Terminal it shows correct version, but in VC terminal it allways shows 8.1 version which I dont know from where is comming from. Does anyone knows how to solve this?

The Visual Studio Code's PHP version comes from your Windows PHP version.
so if you want to change it, you must change the PHP directory path in your windows Environment Variables.  
First Copy the path of your PHP:


Go to your PHP directory where the php.exe file exists
Copy the exact path from Windows Explorer like below image

Then go to ThisPC and Right-Click inside the white area
Click Properties
Click Advanced system settings 

Inside the new window, click the Environment Variables

Double left-Click on path 

Found the old PHP path and replace your new one (if there is not any PHP path, then create one)

Click on the OK buttons in all windows
Close and Open again your terminals.

Congrats! Your PHP version must be updated.

mohammad pourmami's answer is correct, but let me add a few simpler tricks for you.
So you need to update your Windows Environment variables to add the new PHP version to PATH.
Since you are using Laragon, you don't need to do this manually, Laragon will do it for you with just one click ( or two ).
Take Laragon,
Menu -> Tools -> Path - Add Laragon to Path

And that's it, Laragon will update your Environment variables and update PHP's path with the currently selected version.
Sometimes I also first click Remove Laragon from Path and then click Add Laragon to Path, it's sort of become a habit.
Important
After you have updated the PATH, you need to close ALL running instances of Vscode and then open vscode again for your changes to reflect in vscode
